# Testing React with Mocha and Chai

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, tdd, chai

I have a simple javascript calculator app, that I want to learn test-driven development using Mocha and Chai.

**calculator_app.js**

```
class calculator_app extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        formdata: ''
      };

      this._onAdd  = this._onAdd.bind(this);
      this._onSubtract  = this._onSubtract.bind(this);
      this._onMultiply  = this._onMultiply.bind(this);
      this._onDivide = this._onDivide.bind(this);
      this._onClear = this._onClear.bind(this);
      this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
    }

    sayHello() {
        return 'hello';
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <App>
                {infoform}
                <MyHeader/>
                <Section>
                <Box colorIndex="brand">
                    <Heading style={{color: '#ffffff'}} id='header1'>Frosties Calculator</Heading>
                </Box>
                    <Box alignSelf="center" />
                    <Box>
                        <Box>
                            <Header size="small" colorIndex="grey-2" id='header2' />
                            <Box colorIndex="light-2" pad={{ horizontal: 'medium', vertical: 'medium', between: 'medium' }}>
                                <Box colorIndex="light-1" pad="large" separator="all">
                                    <Heading strong={true} id='header3'>Calculator</Heading>    
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        Sample code to display a calculator. 
                                    </Paragraph>                                
                                </Box>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Section>
                <MyFooter/>
            </App>
        );
    }
}

export default calculator_app;
```

**calculator_app.test.js**

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const calculator = require('../src/js/components/calculator_app.js');

describe('calculator', function () {
  describe('sayHello()', function () {

        it('app should return hello', function () {
          let result = calculator.sayHello();
          assert.equal(result, 'hello');
        });
    });
});
```

When I try running the calculator_app.test to check the return on the sayHello function, I get the following error:

> 0 passing (107ms)  1 failing  1) calculator
>         sayHello()
>           app should return hello:
>       TypeError: calculator.sayHello is not a function
>        at Context. (C:/Users/maherni/Desktop/Projects/JavaScript/calculator_app/test/calculator_app.test.js:8:29)

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, I have check the path and scture of my test file

Comment: have you looked at using `enzyme` - https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you try to call the method `sayHello` without instantiating the `calculator` React Component class. Try this:

```
    it('app should return hello', function () {
      let result = new calculator().sayHello();
      assert.equal(result, 'hello');
    });
```

If you want to test the behavior of the `render` method, you should indeed take a look at [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme), as [Paul Fitzgerald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4425849/paul-fitzgerald) suggested.

Comment: That fixed my issue, thank you.

I have one more question, If I want to run multiple tests against calculator, will I have to call all tests this way?

Comment: Yes. It is recommended to write one test for each behavior/method. That way you can keep your tests decoupled from one another, and you avoid ugly side effects in more complex tests.